# how can I stop everything else loading, with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having a lot of trouble with some jquery and ajax in my scripts.js file. I've been trying to follow patterns in console but it is all very frustratingly unpredictable. Is ajax always like that? (The code I'm working on is stuff someone else did.)

How could I put in a line of code that says basically, 'stop, and don't do anything else! no more loads of anything - until another button is clicked, or action called from somewhere else'.

I think that could help fix some of my problems.

I've put my function below, and where I want it all to stop. Thanks for any help.

```
function initialize_google_maps2() {

     console.log('google maps 2 initialized'); 
    var currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(map_latitude, map_longitude);
    var zoom = 10;
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: zoom,
        center: currentlatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, // ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID
        streetViewControl: false
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"), myOptions);


    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: currentlatlng, icon:{oppacity:0}});
   // map.setCenter(currentlatlng);

    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map,
        fillOpacity: 0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        strokeOpacity: 0.7,
        radius: 10000,
    });

    circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
    console.log('end of initialize google 2 function')


// stop, and don't do anything else! no more loads of anything - until another button is clicked, or action called from
//somewhere else
  }
```

Comment: Just wrap everything else you don't want to load in a function bound to a click event, or the likes of it?

Comment: there is no ajax shown in your code. No way to know what you are trying to stop

Answer (score 0):

You can use .ajaxStop() of JQuery. I hope I answered your question

Comment: How would I call it? Just did a quick google and it said to use it with 'Before Send' but not sure how that works.

Comment: 'Before Send' callback is not required. I hope this link would work for you http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/. This is helpful when your request is complete and you want to do something after that.

Comment: If you want prevent any event to happen you can call e.preventDefault() method

Comment: On second thoughts you can just 'return' from the function where you want to stop.